# MAX31855 giving NaN after some readings

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, temperature-sensor

In my current project I am measuring temperature using K-type thermocouple and MAX31855 breakout board and Arduino uno.

I have used Adafruit-max31855 library and example code from that library. But monitoring on serial monitor after some reading it is giving **NaN**.

Here is the code I have used:

```
#include "Adafruit_MAX31855.h"

int thermoDO = 5;
int thermoCS = 6;
int thermoCLK = 7;

Adafruit_MAX31855 thermocouple(thermoCLK, thermoCS, thermoDO);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("MAX31855 test");
  // wait for MAX chip to stabilize
  delay(500);
}

void loop() {
  // basic readout test, just print the current temp
   Serial.print("Internal Temp = ");
   Serial.println(thermocouple.readInternal());

   double c = thermocouple.readCelsius();
   if (isnan(c)) {
     Serial.println("Something wrong with thermocouple!");
   } else {
     Serial.print("C = "); 
     Serial.println(c);
   }
   //Serial.print("F = ");
   //Serial.println(thermocouple.readFarenheit());

   delay(1000);
}
```

Circuit Diagram:

[image: max31855 arduino]

Output:

[image: output]

What could be the possible error for this and how can I solve this?

Comment: Post your sketch and schematic. Otherwise, no razonable answer can be produced.

Comment: Add the actual problematic output from the Serial Monitor. We need to know whether you're gettin NaN from the internal temperature reading or the thermocouple reading.

Comment: Maybe this could help: https://forums.adafruit.com/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=119545

Comment: Does the error appear after a set time? Does it come good if you wiggle the wires? What about if you wiggle the thermocouple soldered to the board? Do you have another Adafruit board to compare it with?

Comment: Did Edgar Bonet's answer give you any answers. Did it solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try to `Serial.println(thermocouple.readError())`. It will give you an
error code, which is a bit field:

- 1 = open circuit
- 2 = short to ground
- 4 = short to Vcc

C.f. the
[datasheet](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/MAX31855.pdf#page=10).